# Necessary diagnostics of multiple quantile regression

Tags: regression, r, diagnostic, quantile-regression, reporting

I am wondering **what are necessary statistics for multiple quantile regression model**.
I am considering creating a model e.g. using the `quantreg` R package:

```
model <- rq(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, tau = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), data = df,  method='fn')
```

To obtain estimates, 95% confidence intervals and $p$-values for each independent variable across all `tau`s, I simply use `summary`:

```
summary(model, se = "boot")
```

and report outcomes as:

1. tables will all aforementioned results
2. figures showing estimated coefficients with 95% CI of independent variables across `tau`s.

**Questions:**

1. Is my approach appropriate for this kind of statistics?
2. Does multiple quantile regression model require any diagnostic plot or test for proving its good construction?